# Colon with 'r' in string not working as desired under zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I try to run code under `zsh`

```
a=123
b="$a:r"
echo $b
```

which I want the result to be `123:r`, but it turns out to be

```
123 # without ":r"
```

And the same thing for character `t`, `q`.

However, if I run it under `bash`, it brings me the desired result `123:r`.

If I add `{}`, runs

```
a=123
b="${a}:r"
echo $b
```

which also brings the desired result.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

In zsh, `"$a:r"` is the same as `"${a:r}"` by default.

To quote from [the documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) (Emphasis added):

> `${name}`
>
> The value, if any, of the parameter name is substituted. The braces are required if the expansion is to be followed by a letter, digit, or underscore that is not to be interpreted as part of name. In addition, more complicated forms of substitution usually require the braces to be present; **exceptions, which only apply if the option KSH_ARRAYS is not set, are a single subscript or any colon modifiers appearing after the name**, or any of the characters ‘^’, ‘=’, ‘~’, ‘#’ or ‘+’ appearing before the name, all of which work with or without braces.

The `:r` modifer [means](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers):

> Remove a filename extension leaving the root name. Strings with no filename extension are not altered. A filename extension is a ‘.’ followed by any number of characters (including zero) that are neither ‘.’ nor ‘/’ and that continue to the end of the string. For example, the extension of ‘foo.orig.c’ is ‘.c’, and ‘dir.c/foo’ has no extension.

To disable this behavior:

```
$ setopt KSH_ARRAYS
```

(Note: Doing this on my setup actually causes zsh to segfault; the option changes behavior in multiple ways, one of which conflicts badly with something in my `.zshrc`. Your results may vary.)