# zsh command with bad local forwarding

Tags: unix, ssh, cluster-computing, zsh

I am trying to make a terminal command to automate connecting to a cluster and have included the following in my .zsh file

```
function access_cluster(){

ssh -N -f -L localhost:$2:localhost:$1 [cluster name] }
```

When I run `access_cluster 7777 9999` from the terminal, however, I receive the following message:

`Bad local forwarding specification 'localhost:9999ocalhost:7777`

zsh seems to be ignoring the :l in my command, how can I fix this? I am running macOS Big Sur 11.3.1

Comment: Just use '${2}' and '${1}'

Comment: I changed the line to `ssh -N -f -L localhost:${2}:localhost:${1} [name]` and get the same error message

Comment: The `:l` is being interpreted as a lowercasing operator. Try `x=FOO; echo $x:l`. It *should* work if you place the braces around the parameter name, since `$2:l` is short for `${2:l}`. The braces prevent the `:` from being recognized as part of the the expansion.

Comment: That said, I don't think using `localhost` is valid for the `host` component, only the bind address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colon with 'r' in string not working as desired under zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604684/colon-with-r-in-string-not-working-as-desired-under-zsh) (Just replace :r with :l and it's your issue too)

Comment: @kofemann 's original reply did work. I forgot to re-sync the updated .zshrc after saving. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port forwarding format is wrong. It should be like:

```
ssh -L local_port:destination_server_ip:remote_port
```

So in your case it should be as:

```
ssh -L $2:localhost:$1  cluster_name
```

Comment: You'll still need `${2}:localhost:$1` to avoid triggering `zsh`'s history-style expansion of `$2:l`.